# Where are Androids’ developer options stored?

Tags: system, system-apps, java, sqlite

Can anyone please tell me, where Androids’ developer options are stored?

I’m trying to modify the Pointer Location developer option in [this](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/cm-13.0/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/PointerLocationView.java) file.

After recompiling Android, where is the file containing the modified sqlite database, system process or binary file, as I would like to exchange the new file with the one on my smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

The **Developer options** are stored in the file:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
```

Pay attention that this is a database stored on file that includes also other saved options / settings, so just copying over another db file might cause unexpected behaviors.

As pointed out by @Gokul NC in the comments, this is not applicable since Marshmallow.

Comment: So how to avoid such unexpected behavior? I overwrote a file and the app won't start. I used chmod/chown to match original. What else should I watch out for?

Answer (score 1):

On my LineageOS on Android Nougat the file was located at

```
/data/system/users/0/settings_global.xml
```

I guess the `0` after the `/users`/ is my user id.
If this location differs from android version // distribution you might want to find the file via something like

```
find | grep "settings_global.xml"
```

or another search string using the `adb shell` or another way to access the shell on your device.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 6.0 and above, it can be found inside the SharedPreferences file:

```
/data/data/com.android.settings/databases/com.android.settings_preferences.xml
```